# Telethon in @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats= ... )) can’t transfer the current list of identifiers from the database

Tags: python, asynchronous, telethon, python-3.12

I am writing a script using the Telethon library. In the "chats" parameter in the event constructor (`@client.on(events.NewMessage())`) a list of telegram channel IDs is transmitted

I also use SQLite3, the list of identifiers is stored there. It is also possible, while the script is running, to add or remove an identifier from the database

The problem is that I don’t understand how to make sure that the “chats” parameter always receives the current list from the database, which is passed from the `db_parschannel()` function

```
api_id = API_ID
api_hash = API_HASH
client = TelegramClient('my_session', api_id, api_hash, system_version='4.16.30-vxCUSTOM')

channel_test = CHANNEL_TEST
channel_PL = CHANNEL_PL
channel_from_pars = asyncio.run(db_parschannel())
names_channel = asyncio.run(get_from_db_parschannel())

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_from_pars))
async def parsing_new_message(event):

    if event.message.message != "":
        if hasattr(event.message.peer_id, "channel_id"):
            if int(f"-100{event.message.peer_id.channel_id}") in list(names_channel):
                print(names_channel[int(f"-100{event.message.peer_id.channel_id}")])

    pasring_text = event.message

    await client.send_message(channel_PL, pasring_text)
```

Getting a list of identifiers from the database

```
async def db_parschannel():
conn = sqlite3.connect('database/id_telega.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

    CHANNEL_FROM_PARS = [i[0] for i in cursor.execute("SELECT id_channel from channels")]
    
    return CHANNEL_FROM_PARS
```

If I try to do something like:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=asyncio.run(db_parschannel())
```

It still doesn’t work, and if you run the script and then delete/add something, it will take over the old list and use it until I restart the script

I also tried something like:

```
channel_from_pars = asyncio.run(db_parschannel())

async def upd_id_channel():
global channel_from_pars
channel_from_pars = await db_parschannel()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_from_pars))
async def parsing_new_message(event):
await upd_id_channel()
```

But it didn't help either

Comment: While this is the only thing that came to mind, add a check at the beginning of the function: `if int(f"-100{event.message.peer_id.channel_id}") in await db_parschannel():`
But this is not very convenient because in this way the script reacts to all channels to which you are subscribed, and if one channel sent a message (or several at once) and at the same moment the channel I need sent a message, the event handler may not work on because there is a certain timeout for event processing.